# C# winforms form show cmd

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating a UI application in VS without using the form designer. After creating a new form and compiling everything works good. Form is rendered, but also a `cmd` console is rendered! Why console is rendered with form?

I create in VS empty C# project and create `Program.cs` and `MainWindow.cs`

**Program.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args"></param>
/// 
[STAThread]
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new MainWindow());
}
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public class MainWindow : Form
{
    private Form _mainWindowForm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        _mainWindowForm = new Form();

        _mainWindowForm.Text = "Test";
        _mainWindowForm.Width = 800;
        _mainWindowForm.Height = 700;
    }
}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: just curious...why not just use a forms type of project? If you really want to do it by hand, create a forms project, and look for the code you are missing.

Comment: Becouse my agent dont want to use desinger.

Comment: YES empty c# project from VS

Comment: what is VS version?

Comment: seriously. just create a forms project (on another computer if you are "not allowed") and see what you are missing.

Comment: You are using a Console Application. The console will show up when you run your app. If you want to use Forms, create a Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio. You don't need to use the designer to create the forms, you can create them in code. delete Form1.cs and in the Program.cs file you can create a form in code manually.

Comment: @Ivan Look in to Project Properties > Application Tab > Output type combo box: Change it to Windows Application.

Comment: Create a Windows Forms Application instead of a Console Application. You don't have to use the Designer. In fact, I would heartily recommend that you DO NOT USE IT. It's for amateurs IMO. You are far better off writing your own Form classes. It gives you greater control and better source control management. Just create a Windows Forms Application, remove the default form that is created, then create a class that extends Form on your own and open it via Program.cs. You'll want to create a base Form that all your forms can extend, including common core UI code.

Comment: The designer is the one of the main pillars of rapid application development using Winforms, IMO.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Rapid, but all too often bad. You can do better, more precise (and more) rapid app dev without it. Fine for beginners, of course, but professional developers should know better.

Comment: @ManoDestra I disagree :) It's suitable for both beginners and professionals. But professionals know better how to get the most out of it.

Comment: @RezaAghaei By creating unnecessary binary files that can't be checked for differences causing source control problems and giving you a lesser degree of fine grained control over the view, as well as auto generated partial class files that change the order of code randomly making diff checks ever harder? And doing all of it by hand slower than you can do in code that can be compared? No thanks. Pros don't use tools written for beginners where they don't have full control over the source code. Good luck with that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on project and select Properties option. In the Application tab You will see project output. Here you need to select Windows Application as the project output.

[image: Project properties window]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio. Delete the autogenerated Form1.cs form and open the Program.cs file and do something like this:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var myForm = new Form();
        myForm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        // Do anything else to the form here in code

        Application.Run(myForm);
    }
```